# Django and one-time links with data

Tags: python, django, forms

I think I have a simple case here but I'm not finding good examples of the implementation ( or probably failing to understand).

After the user (not logged in) types his username to a form, Django would generate a unique URL based of this data (encoded in URL?) for the user that can be accessed once and within 5 minutes. Based on that URL (after clicking it) the data (username) would be decoded and ready for use in this one-time view.

Simple scenario if needed: user nimda fills the form and then is redirected (for example) to a view that shows the generated URL. Then nimda clicks the generated URL and a view is shown with the data he or she typed into the form

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need that url you could save data to the session and send the user to a specific url.
The view connected to the url generates content depending on the (anonymous) users session. The user can see the content as long as you sessions last or you implement a time stamp an check this before delivering content.

If you need the url:

1. Build a model connected with the sessions with url and a time stamp.
2. Configure the urls.py for the url-model like
   url(r'^dataUrl/(?P[0-9]+)/$', PostDelete.as_view()),
3. Assign the user session and the entered data (saved to the session) with 
   the url-model.
4. When delivering the content check for the random-url-part, and the timestamp and deliver the date (or not ;)  )

You can access the session in a cvb's like this:

```
class YourClassName(TemplateView):
    template_name = ""
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(YourClassName , self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      DataYouNeed = self.request.session["SessionVariableOfTheUser"]
      userDAta = self.request.user #if this is usefull         `
```

or in a createView:

```
class URLCreate(CreateView):
    model = randomUrl
    template_name = "entryCreate.html"
    success_url = "../xyz/"
    form_class = UrlCreateForm 
    # if you like to change the success-url
    def get_success_url(self):
      #print dir(self.object.instance)
      #print self.object.instance.id
      url = "../bringMeTo/%s" % self.object.instance.id
      return url

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        self.request.session["formData"]= form.instance
        return super(URLCreate, self).form_valid(form)
    pass
```

This is not a ready solution! Just an inspiration for a start.

Comment: thanks for the help! I need the URL since I'm sending the URL to user's mobile via SMS. Do you have an example of your implementation?

Comment: No. I don't have a copy'n-past-ready implementation. But i think it's quite straight forward.

Comment: That's ok. Generating the url for the view is the problem I'm having atm